# Create a 'member' object in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm working on a discord bot, using the [`discord.py`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library, that needs to query the members in a [`VoiceChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#voicechannel) and process that data. My problem is that in developing this bot I sometimes don't have access to a voice channel with enough members to test my bot with.

Is there a simple way to create a [`Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#member) object in the backend so I don't always have to have access to a voice channel with several people connected? Something like:

```py
import discord
new_nember = discord.Member(name="something")
```

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using a [`VoiceChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#voicechannel)?

To get a [`Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#member), you can use different method:

- To get all the members of a [`Guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#guild), use [`Guild.members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.members).
- If you know the ID of a member, you can use [`Guild.get_member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_member).
- If you want to get a member based on their name, you can use [`Guild.get_member_named`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_member_named).

The most complete lookup can be done using [`commands.MemberConverter.convert`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.converter.MemberConverter.convert), where lookups by `ID`, `mention`, `name#discrim`, `name` and `nickname` are done in this order.

Example:

```py
import discord, asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    guild = bot.get_guild(PUT THE SERVER ID HERE)
    member1 = guild.get_member(PUT A MEMBER ID HERE)
    member2 = guild.get_member_named("User#Discrim")
    member3 = commands.converter.MemberConverter().convert("User")
```

Comment: I'm using a voice channel because I just want to use the active users in that channel since that'll be the use case when my bot is finished.

Comment: Whenever I try to initialize a `Member` object it wants me to provide a whole load of extra data that I'm not sure where to get it. I don't have any issues getting the member list from the server/guild or a voice channel, just creating a pseudo member object for testings

If I do this:
import discord
discord.Member()

I get

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required keyword-only arguments: 'data', 'guild', and 'state'
```